# How to transform a multiple xts list into one xts object?

Tags: r, list, xts

I have a `list` named `Rets` with  `33 xts class objects`. Each one of those `xts objects` is "quarterly" and have daily returns of 3 different portfolios, like this:

```
> print(Rets[[1]][,1:3])
           Equal.Weighted      MVLedoit      MVSample
2003-01-02   2.598379e-02  0.0074618827  0.0085061439
2003-01-03  -3.419687e-03 -0.0109129714 -0.0107993433
2003-01-06   3.120466e-02 -0.0027083783 -0.0011993601
.
.
.
2003-04-28   2.073540e-02  0.0026789571  0.0032035582
2003-04-29   1.492713e-02  0.0009878566 -0.0019401993
2003-04-30   2.898973e-04  0.0078070394  0.0074441371

> print(Rets[[2]][,1:3])
           Equal.Weighted      MVLedoit      MVSample
2003-05-02   0.0165136926  0.0084945856  9.398209e-03
2003-05-05  -0.0036702400  0.0092221437  8.448889e-03
2003-05-06  -0.0125257806  0.0014797926  6.905171e-04
.
.
.
2003-08-27   0.0131081444  0.0128875785  1.358910e-02
2003-08-28  -0.0028180975  0.0143124389  1.439714e-02
2003-08-29   0.0028192886  0.0050242460  4.571573e-03
```

How can I do to create a single `xts object` containing all information?

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't pkg:zoo and by extension pkg:xts have an `rbind` method? So have you tried `do.call('rbind', Rets)`?

Comment: Thank you! Iam new in R and dont know some of the basic commands. I  tried `ALLRets <- do.call('rbind', Rets)` and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BondedBust Thank you for you comment. The command is easy as you say:

```
ALLRets <- do.call('rbind', Rets)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. It is always good to post a good comment that solves your problem as an answer so that other people can benefit when they see it. Feel free to accept it as well, it is encouraged to do it. +1